# how to patch threading.Lock methods using unittest patch decorator

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I'm trying to test a multithreaded code using pytest in python, I'm trying to patch threading objects methods to test the logic.

Below is showed a minimal code of what I'm doing:

*my_project/main.py*

```py
from threading import Thread, Lock

class MyThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.lock = Lock() 
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def run(self):
    with self.lock:
      # my code
```

*tests/test_my_thread.py*

```py
from unittest.mock import patch 
import my_project.main 

@patch("my_project.main.Thread.start")
def patch_thread_start():
  print("patching start ")

@patch("my_project.main.Lock.acquire")
def patch_lock_a():
  print("patching acquire ")

@patch("my_project.main.Lock.release")
def patch_lock_r():
  print("patching release ")
```

When I run this code the `Thread.start` method is patched normally but the `acquire` method always give me this error:

> /usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:1366: AttributeError:  does not have the attribute 'acquire'

Comment: Can you update your code so that it's reproducible?

Comment: @ntriisii Could you give a feedback to my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

### Use of patch.object()

Your question is not very clear, but my intention with this answer is to suggest you how to solve some errors in your test code:

- add a `setUp()` method which creates an instance of the class `MyThread`
- substitute function `patch()` with `patch.object()`

Your file *tests/test_my_thread.py* could be modified as followed:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import my_project.main

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.sut = my_project.main.MyThread()

    def test_patch_thread_start(self):
        with patch.object(self.sut, "start") as mock_start:
            mock_start.side_effect = print("patching start")
            self.sut.start()

    def test_patch_lock_a(self):
        with patch.object(self.sut, "lock") as mock_lock:
            mock_lock.aquire.side_effect = print("patching acquire")
            self.sut.start()

    def test_patch_lock_r(self):
        with patch.object(self.sut, "lock") as mock_lock:
            mock_lock.release.side_effect = print("patching release")
            self.sut.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You have to modify your file *my_project/main.py* as followed:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.lock = Lock()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        #with self.lock:      <--------- Remove this context manager
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.lock.release()
```

The output of the execution of the file test_my_thread.py in my system is:

```
patching acquire
patching release
patching start
```